# Blender 2.83 crashes when deleting the default cube with OpenCL GPU Rendering (Revenge of the default cube?)

Tags: rendering, gpu, opencl

I wanted to try out GPU rendering with my AMD R9 Fury GPU. The Problem: When I enable OpenCL and GPU rendering and try to delete the default cube in the rendered viewport, blender crashes. When I hit F12 to render, my whole PC locks up and gets stuck in a boot loop. Is this a bug or a problem with my GPU?

Comment: The revenge of the AMD R9:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=R9

Comment: Ouch. CPU rendering it is. Thanks!